# Is the wedge sum of a well pointed space independant of the base point?

Tags: algebraic-topology

At the beginning of my algebraic topology course, one of the exercise was to prove that the homotopy type of the wedge sum of a well-pointed path-connected space $(A,a_0)$ with a pointed space $(B,b_0)$ is independant of the base point in $A$, where a well-pointed space is defined as a pair $(X,x)$ having the homotopy extension property.

To guide us, we first had to prove that for any point $a_1 \in A$, there was a homotopy equivalence $g: A \to A$ sending $a_0$ on $a_1$. We can do this by taking any path between $a_0$ and $a_1$ and using the homotopy extension property. Then, the argument given in the corrected version is that the function $h: (A,a_0) \vee (B,b_0) \to (A,a_1) \vee (B,b_0),$ defined by $\forall a \in A,h(a) = g(a),\forall b \in B, h(b) = b$, is "clearly" an homotopy equivalence.

But for me it’s not clear at all. If we have $f: A \to A$ the homotopy equivalence inverse of $g$, $f \circ g$ is homotopic to the identity, but this homotopy moves the point $a_0$ along the path between $a_0$ and $a_1$, therefore I can’t use this homotopy to show that $h$ is a homotopy equivalence, because the point $a_0$ is fixed by the wedge sum.

So here’s my question : am I correct in the fact that the given proof is not sufficient, and if yes, what is a correct proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not even correct.

Here is a counter example. The [comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) $C$ is freely contractible. It is well-pointed when given the basepoint $(0,0)$. Thus $(C,(0,0))$ has the pointed homotopy type of a point. On the other hand, the inclusion $(0,1)\hookrightarrow C$ is not a cofibration, and it is well-known that $(C,(0,1))$ *does not* have the pointed homotopy type of a point. Thus there is a pointed homotopy equivalence
$$(C,(0,0))\vee B\simeq B$$
for any pointed space $B$. On the other hand there is no pointed homotopy equivalence
$$(C,(0,1))\vee \ast\not\simeq \ast.$$

You were a bit imprecise in the statement since you did not specify whether you mean pointed or unpointed homotopy equivalence. Since you are using basepoints I assume you mean the former. In case you were using the latter, consider the following wedge
$$(C,(0,1))\vee (C,(0,1))$$
By the above this space is not pointed contractible ($(C,(0,1))$ retracts off of it). On the other hand, this space is neither [freely contractible](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Double_comb_space). In particular is cannot be equivalent (either pointed or unpointed) to
$$(C,(0,0))\vee (C,(0,1))\simeq (C,(0,1))$$
since this space *is* freely contractible.

The correct statement is the following:

> Let $A$ be a path-connected space and $a_0,a_1\in A$. Assume that the based spaces $(A,a_0)$ and $(A,a_1)$ are well-pointed. Then $(A,a_0)$ and $(A,a_1)$ have the same pointed homotopy type. In particular, if $B$ is any pointed space, then
> $$(A,a_0)\vee B\simeq (A,a_1)\vee B$$
> as pointed spaces.

Sketch Proof: Choose a path $l:I\rightarrow A$ from $a_0$ to $a_1$. Apply the HEP to the pair $(id_A,l)$ to get a free map $f:A\rightarrow A$ with $f\simeq_{free}id_A$ and $f(a_0)=l(1)=a_1$. We consider $f$ a pointed map $f:(A,a_0)\rightarrow (A,a_1)$. Then $f$ is a free homotopy equivalence. Since both inclusions $a_0,a_1\hookrightarrow A$ are cofibrations $f$ is also a pointed homotopy equivalence. Thus there is a map $g:(A,a_1)\rightarrow (A,a_0)$ and homotopies $gf\simeq id_A$ rel $a_0$ and $fg\simeq id_A$ rel $a_1$.

In this case, for any pointed space $B$
$$f\vee 1:(A,a_0)\vee B\rightarrow (A,a_1)\vee B$$
is a pointed homotopy equivalence with pointed inverse
$$g\vee 1:(A,a_1)\vee B\rightarrow (A,a_0)\vee B.$$

Comment: Thanks ! I think the exercise was about unpointed homotopy.